# Disable mass assignment protection for all models across all tests

Tags: laravel, mass-assignment

is there a way to disable mass assignment protection for all models across all tests without having to duplicate this over and over?
`FooTest`

```php
Foo::unguard();
Bar::unguard();
Baz::unguard();
Foo::create(['column' => 'value']);
Bar::create(['column' => 'value']);
Baz::create(['column' => 'value']);
```

`BarTest`

```php
Foo::unguard();
Bar::unguard();
Baz::unguard();
Foo::create(['column' => 'value']);
Bar::create(['column' => 'value']);
Baz::create(['column' => 'value']);
```

`BazTest`

```php
Foo::unguard();
Bar::unguard();
Baz::unguard();
Foo::create(['column' => 'value']);
Bar::create(['column' => 'value']);
Baz::create(['column' => 'value']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out using the `TestCase` every Test class extends, and the `Eloquen\Model` every model extends.
`tests/TestCase.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Model::unguard();
    }
}
```